# JasperReports: using variable in variable's expression

Tags: variables, jasper-reports

I am using *Jaspersoft Studio* and am trying to set a variable to the value of another variable (well actually, I will need a sum of two variables in another variable)

So I have two variables, A and B. I need to put A in B. Whenever I use a textfield to output A, it works fine. If in the variable B, I put a ($V{A}), and I try to print B, I get a null.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this happens?

Report X contains subreport Y which returns a variable

```
<returnValue subreportVariable="EXPENDITURES_TOTAL_VAR" toVariable="EXPENDITURES_TOTAL_VAR" incrementerFactoryClass=""/>
```

(note the same variable name in both reports)

Report X then contains another variable

```
<variable name="STOTAL_VAR" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{EXPENDITURES_TOTAL_VAR}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

This WORKS:

```
    <textField>
        <reportElement x="120" y="1" width="70" height="30" uuid="f0e81b0f-ddd3-4f31-9711-cfdeb64f36b2"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{EXPENDITURES_TOTAL_VAR}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

This does not:

```
    <textField>
        <reportElement x="310" y="1" width="100" height="30" uuid="263973e7-33b1-4343-a76c-3edbe5506d66"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{STOTAL_VAR}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

Comment: Please supply a simple JRXML to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You only supplied fragments of a JRXML, so I have to guess. I assume your `variable name="STOTAL_VAR"` declaration is processed before the subreport is executed. Thus, `STOTAL_VAR` is initialized with some empty value of `EXPENDITURES_TOTAL_VAR` at that time. When the subreport is executed, `EXPENDITURES_TOTAL_VAR` gets a new value, but that is too late for `STOTAL_VAR`.

Comment: yes, yes, this is what I had in mind as well. is there any way to force it to be evaluated AFTER the other var is evaluated?

Comment: As far as I know no. But my JasperReports knowledge is quite limited.

Answer (score 1):

As this is one of the first SO hits when searching for Jasper reports and use variable within other variable and this doesn't give any help - maybe this answer here can help others who search for an answer for how to use a variable within another variable in an iReport:

Taken from here: http://www.jasperassistant.com/docs/guide/ch06s08.html, the short answer is:

Yes you can use a variable within another variable within an iReport - but the variable which you want to use in the other variable must be declared first - so the sequence of the variable matters.

Hope this helps someone.